# Color phenomenon with MOPA Fiber laser on stainless steel

Tags: laser

I just got a **20W MOPA fiber laser** and of course the first thing I do is mark color on **stainless steel**.

The center of the squares pictured are the color for which I set the settings. I am wondering why there are those columns of other color on the left and right sides.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see one square with bars, I see two overlapping squares, as illuminated here:

[image: A red and yellow marking on two overlapping squares]

The reason for them might be manifold, but to me, it seems the most likely cause is bad focussing or a mechanical issue, where between two passes the laser or workpiece were moved by a tiny amount. You also see this offset with the Y you see that there are two lines that are separated by the same distance as the two boxes are shifted to one another.

Comment: Very interesting. I think these were marked with only one pass. If we look at the letter "e," it also has that dark and lighter shading even though it was one pass. Does seeing this change or confirm any of your suspicions? The workpiece isn't flat. Could that be the cause?